# Coupon Collector Problem - Number of necessary trials to reach a given probability to be successful.

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, coupon-collector

I have been looking into the [Coupon Collector Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) and I can't find a formula to calculate the number of trials needed to collect all the coupons in X% of the attempts. Let me explain. The formula to calculate the expected number of trials needed to collect all coupons tells us the number of trials that in (approximately) 50% of the attempts will allow us to collect all coupons. Does anyone know how to calculate the number of trials needed for an arbitrary level of confidence e.g. the number of trials that in 75% of the attempts will allow us to collect all the coupons?

If we look at the formula below I would like to change $p$ (probability to collect all coupons) with an arbitrary probability e.g. 0.75 and given $m$ (e.g. 10) solve the equation for $k$.

$$p = \sum^{m}_{i=1} (-1)^{i+1} {m \choose i} \left(\frac{m-i}{m}\right)^k$$

Comment: I am only aware of an (easy) formula for the expected number of necessary trials , not for the number of necessary trials to reach a given probability to be successful.

Comment: @Peter thank you for your answer. You don't know the solution but you understood what I am looking for!

Comment: It's not true (though it's approximately true) that the expected number of trials tells us the number of trials that allows us to collect all coupons in $50\%$ of attempts.

Comment: @joriki The distribution is going to be right skewed, in part because of the difficulty of getting the final coupon, so using the expectation may for example overestimate the median

Comment: I think this may be the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155615/probability-of-picking-each-of-m-elements-at-least-once-after-n-trials which would suggest that if you want probability $p$ of having chosen all $m$ types of coupons then you need to select about $m(\log_e(m) -\log_e(-\log_e(p))$ coupons

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be OK with the approximation that about $50\%$ of attempts succeed after the expected number of required coupons, you could take this approximation one step further and approximate the entire distribution by a normal distribution. As is well-known, the number of required coupons can be viewed as the sum of $m$ geometric variables with probabilities $\frac jm$ for $j=1,\ldots,m$, so its mean and variance are, respectively,

\begin{eqnarray}
\mu
&=&\sum_{j=1}^m\frac mj
\\
&=&
mH_m
\\
&\approx&
m(\log m+\gamma)
\end{eqnarray}

(where $H_m$ is the $m$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant)) and

\begin{eqnarray}
\sigma^2
&=&
\sum_{j=1}^m\left(\left(\frac mj\right)^2-\frac mj\right)
\\
&=&
m^2\sum_{j=1}^m\frac1{j^2}-mH_m
\\
&\approx&
m^2\frac{\pi^2}6-m(\log m+\gamma)
\\
&\approx&
m^2\frac{\pi^2}6\;.
\end{eqnarray}

To approximate the number of coupons required to reach a certain probability of completing the collection, we can invert the cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution with this mean and variance:

$$
\frac12\left(1+\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{k-\mu}{\sqrt2\sigma}\right)\right)=p\;,
$$

and thus

\begin{eqnarray}
k&=&\mu+\sqrt2\sigma\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(2p-1)
\\
&\approx&
\left(\log m+\gamma+\frac\pi{\sqrt3}\operatorname{erf}^{-1}(2p-1)\right)m\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: this is exactly what I had in mind! Il mio cuore è per te!

Comment: As my comment on the question says, I think there is a better and simpler approximation of $\Big(\log_e(m) -\log_e\big(-\log_e(p)\big)\Big)m$ which takes account of the shape of the distribution